# Overriding CSS properties for a specific html element

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have the following:

```html
<section class="main_section">
    <article>
    ...
    </article>
</section>
```

In my stylesheet I have:

```css
.main_section article {
    background-color:#fff;
    /* ... */
}
```

The article is styled, and I am happy about it. Now, for a *single* instance of `article`, I want to do the following:

```html
<section class="main_section">
    <article class="special-bg">
    ...
    </article>
</section>
```

Which I have defined:

```css
.special-bg {
    background-color: #276a7f;
}
```

But the class is not setting the background-color. It seems that the styling of the html tag `article` takes precedence, no matter the order of the CSS rules in my stylesheet.

How can I overwrite a CSS property of an styled html tag by using a styling class? Is this at all possible? Any alternative?

Comment: use `.main_section .special-bg` instead. That's a [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a **[CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** issue.

`.main_section article` has a higher specificity value than `.special-bg` selector.

In terms of value:
`Inline Style` > `IDs` > `Classes, Attributes, and Pseudo-classes` > `Element Types and Pseudo-elements`, So the calculation of Specificity of these two CSS selectors would be:

*`.special-bg`*

```
Inline Style    ID   (Pseudo-)Class    (Pseudo-)Element
0               0    1                 0
```

*`.main_section article`*

```
Inline Style    ID   (Pseudo-)Class    (Pseudo-)Element
0               0    1                 1
```

**`11` > `10` => `.main_section article` selector wins!**

You could use the following:

```css
.main_section .special-bg {
  /* Styles goes here... */
}
```

Further reading:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity
- http://cssspecificity.com/

And a great tool to calculate the specificity value:

- http://specificity.keegan.st/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this css

```
.main_section .special-bg{

  background-color: #276a7f !important;

}
```

Comment: `!important` is not needed here too.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
.main_section .special-bg {
    background-color: #276a7f;
}
```

see this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ckxsw/

Something like this would be a useful read: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `!important`, like this:

```
.special-bg {
    background-color: #276a7f !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is very often a sign of bad design. It should be used in special cases. This is not a situation when `important` should be even considered.

Comment: Thanks but I hate important. Not possible to understand what is going on anymore.