# remove border around search field only

Tags: css, input, border, textfield

I'm trying to remove the pesky border around a single search box, not all text/input fields.

I believe this to be the culprit -

```
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=password],
textarea {
    background:none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding:14px 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

To remedy, I've tried (to no avail)-

```
#searchform #s {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Is there is better (ie - working) way to achieve this effect? I want to keep the border on all other text/input fields, only removing on the single search field..

[Live site.](http://www.thelocalrose.com)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `!important` in this case. Even more, there's probably no need to use `#searchform #s` because the `#s` selector itself has a [higher specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329824/overriding-some-properties-for-a-specific-instance-of-an-html-tag/21329995#21329995) than the `input[type=text]`.

Hence, the following could be sufficient:

```css
#s { border: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the search input field in some context that other inputs are not in, you could target that.

Example: if its inside a `<header>` you could do this:

```
header #searchform #s {
    border: none;
}
```

but mabye show us your html and divs around your input field :)