# What is "html input[type="button"]" in bootstrap 2?

Tags: css

I have spent some time searching google and stack but I seem to be running to a wall because of the symbols in it. In my bootstrap 2 CSS file there is a line that has `html input[type="button"]`. I presume this means that any `<input type="button" />` that is used outside of an HTML form gets the styling assigned to that CSS tag?

Comment: Where did you get the 'form' from? :)

Comment: The selector will match any `<input type="button">` inside of `<html>` regardless of whether it's also inside a `<form>` or not.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I did try and could not tell any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. It means any `<input type="button" />` within the `<html>` tag. There is nothing about it being a direct child of `<html>`, nor anything about it not being inside a form.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It means just the opposite. CSS will be applied to all the  `<input type="text"/>` inside HTML tag.

**NOTE:** No tag can exist outside HTML except Doctype as reminded by **Nix**

Comment: The OP doesn't appear to be suggestion "*outside of `<html>`*," but rather "*outside of an HTML `<form>`*."

Comment: "NOTE: No tag can exist outside HTML." Except Doctype. Furthermore, you actually don't even need a html tag in your source. The browser will create it. Pedantic, I know. :)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski :Thank you for pointing that out. I misunderstood OP.

Comment: So what is the point of adding `html` to it, would not the same thing be accomplished without it?

Comment: @Nix *Doctype* isn't an HTML, it is a declaration. (As the [`<html>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#semantics) is the root element of the document).

Comment: You can safely ignore my comment. It is always best practice to include the `html` tag, but if you forget it, the browser will create it for you – but this wasn't always so. @HashemQolami is also correct about Doctype being a declaration and not a tag, so I guess joke is on me. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's all about the [CSS Specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329824/overriding-css-properties-for-a-specific-html-element/21329995#21329995).

`html input[type="button"]` has a higher specificity value than `input[type="button"]` selector. Hence it overrides the same properties used on `input[type="button"]` selector.

#### Specificity measurement

```
html input[type="button"] = 10 + 1 + 1 = 12
input[type="button"]      = 10 + 1     = 11
```

**[Try it!](http://specificity.keegan.st/) online**.

`html input[type="button"]` selector [is used in Normalize.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/01dabd3391591df44f8a0d960bbd14a23723f31d/less/normalize.less#L287) in order to fix a WebKit bug in Android 4.0.*.