# How to offset div columns in CSS grid system

Tags: html, css, grid-system

Does anyone know to offset the first two `div`s that are in side row that have the class `col-3-12` to have an offset of `offset-6-12` and `offset-9-12` to be on the right side of my grid system [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c6R6t/)

**CSS:**

```css
body {
    font:20px/1.2 Verdana, Arial; padding:0px; margin:0px;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px; background-color: red
}
.row {
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
}
.row:after, .row:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row > [class*='col-']:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.row > [class*='col-']:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
    /* edit here*/
    margin:0px 10px 20px 10px 
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float:left; 
    height:300px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    border: 1px solid #000;

}
[class*=col-]:last-of-type {

}
.col-1-12 {
    width: calc((100% - (12/1 - 1) * 20px) / 12 * 1);

}
.col-2-12 {
    width: calc((100% - (12/2 - 1) * 20px) / 12 * 2);
}
.col-3-12 {
    width:  calc((100% - (12/3 - 1) * 20px) / 12 * 3);  
}
.col-4-12 {
    width: calc((100% - (12/4 - 1) * 20px) / 12 * 4);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-3-12 offset-6-12">
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>  
        <div class="col-3-12 offse-9-12">
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3-12">
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>  
        <div class="col-3-12">
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        </div>
        <div class="col-4-12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
        <div class="col-2-12">
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        </div>      
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, for the offset, you need to apply a left margin to floated columns to push them to the right side.

The value of the [`margin-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-left) is equal to:

- *for the **first column** which doesn't have a left margin itself*: the `width` of `previous columns + the gutter width`.
- *for the second column (**the other columns**)*:

  - **<sup>If the column has a left/right `margin` (which creates the gutter):</sup>**
    The `width` of `previous columns` + `the gutter width` + `1/2 gutter width`. (As the columns have a left/right `margin` of 1/2 of the gutter width)
    [image: CSS grid system: columns having left and right margins]
  - **<sup>If the column doesn't have `margin-left` (i.e. the gutter is created only by `margin-right`):</sup>**
    The `width` of `previous columns` + `the gutter width`.
    [image: CSS grid system: columns having right margin]

For instance:

- for the **first column** we calculate the left margin for `.offest-6` as follows:

```css
.row [class*="col-"]:first-child.offest-6-12 {
    margin-left: calc(((100% - (12/6 - 1) * 20px) / 12 * 6 ) + 20px);
    /*                |          width of col-6-12         | + gutter width */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/c6R6t/4/)**.

<sub>**Note:** I used multiple selectors here in order to have a higher **[specificity value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329824/overriding-css-properties-for-a-specific-html-element/21329995#21329995)**.</sub>

Also note that as the columns are floated next to each other, you only need to use the `.offset-*` class for the first column to push them both to the right side.

- And for the **second column** (The other columns) which has left (and right) margin(s):

Since the column has a left (and right) margin (equals 1/2 of the gutter = `10px`)

```css
.row [class*="col-"].offest-6-12 {
    margin-left: calc(((100% - (12/6 - 1) * 20px) / 12 * 6 ) + 20px + 10px);
    /*                |          width of col-6-12         | + (1   + 1/2) gutter width */
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/c6R6t/5/)**. *(The Sassy way: **[Sass version](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9za3k/1/)**)*

### Note

For the second column, you should use `offset-6` because there is another `col-3` column before the current column.

I.e. **You should count the columns' numbers including the offsets**.
For instance: `col-3` +  `col-3 including offset-6` = `12 columns`. If you add more columns, it'll break the flow as it exceeds the limit of 12 columns in a row.

---

> How can we change the code in my CSS to compensate for that `30px` on
>   the end of the `calc()` function, can there be something in the CSS that's
>   in there to make it work without the `30px`. so it can calculate by the
>   `20px` gutter instead of that `30px`

Now the columns have a left and right margin of `10px` which creates the `20px` gutter. That's the reason of adding an extra `10px` to the gutter width for offsets.

We could use `margin-right: 20px` for the columns instead of two margin for left and right side (and no margin for the last column). In this case, we wouldn't need to add the extra `10px`.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/c6R6t/6/)**.

Comment: thanks for you're reply I tried to add the same one to offset-9-12 and the row breaks into two rows how do I get the second one to be on the last 9th column

Comment: btw I'm not using two offsets on two columns

Comment: Ok so I added offset-9-12 to the last col-3-12  and the row breaks into two rows how do I correct that what is the code to correct it

Comment: Ok I added offset-6-12 to the last item in the row and it moves it to  far side but's slightly off on the right side about 10px can you fix that

Comment: What I dont understand now is that when you add another div element after that has col-6-12 it goes to another row and breaks the flow

Comment: imean col-3-12 after offset-6-12

Comment: I'm getting it now what about the 30px can that be in a formula instead of just 30px like 20 + 20/2 + px

Comment: @KDM As I noted at the end of my answer, you should **count the columns'  numbers including the offsets**. For instance: `col-3 +  col-3 has offset-6 = 12 columns`. If you add more columns, it'll breaks the flow as it **exceeds** the limit of 12 columns in a row.

Comment: I now realize that you got to counter the columns being used first and then calculate the offset by what's left over aye, is that it

Comment: I have one question for you. I've seen grid systems use an offset then that offset div uses up the remaining space, is that because of the column size class or some technique they use to fill up the gap or remaining space

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what exactly you mean, but the grid systems often use offsets to push columns to the right (or left for RTL mode) **based on the offset number**. For instance Twitter bootstrap has [`.col-md-offset-*` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) to apply offset to the `.col-md-*` columns. The offset is not related to the columns' size class, It depends on its own offset number.

Comment: how can we change the code in my css to compensate for that 30px on the end of the calc function, can there be something in the css that's in there to make it work without the 30px. so it can calculate by the 20px gutter instead of that 30px

Comment: Yes, now the columns have a left/right margin of `10px` which creates the `20px` gutter. That's the reason of adding an extra `10px` to the gutter width for offsets. However, we could use `margin-right: 20px` for the columns instead of two margin for left and right side (and no margin for the last column). In this case, we wouldn't need to add the extra `10px`.

Comment: I changed the margin-left to 0px and the right to 20px and it still needs an extra 10px on the right what am I doing wrong can you use my code and make a jsFiddle show me the changes you made if you can make it work.

Comment: You've been a great help, you helped me twice in a row this week thanks heaps. We should exchange email address's is you want programmer to programmer chat

Comment: Don't mention it :) My pleasure. My email address is: my firstname at lastname dot com :)

Comment: Just what i needed for my auto generated SASS grid. Thanx!