# CSS precedence based on parent div

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

If you view the following code in a browser the link appears red. I would expect it to be green because the secondary div is nested inside the primary div. It appears the color is determined by the order of the elements in the css file. If I move .secondary after .primary the link is green.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .secondary a {
            color: green;
        }

        .primary a {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="primary">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Other than changing the order in the file how can I make the link respect the color from its parent div?

**EDIT:** This is a very simplified example. In practice there could be many other div tags between the primary and secondary classes.

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dyizc)

Comment: I guess it is because the parent overwrites the child when being defined after the child. I didn't know this, +1 as very good question.

Comment: Order does impact CSS rules precedence.  You would have to make a rule `.primary .secondary a {` to enforce the desired color.  Or use 'important', but that's discouraged.

Comment: Is `secondary` always nested inside `primary`? Several of the answers are making this assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the two selector have the same specificity. The only thing that CSS knows to do with selectors of the same specificity is to choose the most recent one

Thus, you need to make the specificity of the child more than the firsts, one way is to put

```
.primary .secondary a {
    color:green;
}
```

Another way would be to put the element type in addition to the class

This is the reason why it is proper formatting to structure your CSS as the page it is laid out in the HTML, with parents coming before children

For more information as to how specificity is determined, [check here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: It looks like that is as close as we can get. It would be great if I could nest another primary div under secondary and have the link be the "primary" color. This should work for my example though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you used `.primary > a` as the selector, then it would only match anchors that are immediate children of the class.

Of course then you couldn't do something like:

```
<div class="primary">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. In fact the second selector overrides the first one because they both have the same **[specificity value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329824/overriding-css-properties-for-a-specific-html-element/21329995#21329995)**:.

> In terms of value:
>   `Inline Style` > `IDs` > `Classes` > `Attributes, and Pseudo-classes` > `Element Types and Pseudo-elements`.

You can use a selector with higher specificity value to override the CSS declaration.

For instance:

```css
div.secondary a { /* Specificity value = 12 */
    color: green;
}
```

Or:

```css
.primary .secondary a {  /* Specificity value = 21 */
    color: green;
}
```

Here is an **[online tool](http://specificity.keegan.st/)** to calculate the CSS Specificity.

Comment: I was looking for that calculator

Answer (score 2):

If you want the selector to respect the direct parent, you need to use the direct descendant selector `>`:

```
.primary > a {
    color: red;
}
```

Which translates to anchors *only* with a direct parent with class `.primary`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this great article about [css selector specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Since your two rules are equivalent the one that comes last takes precidence. In order to prevent that you can make them more specific using the following:

```
div.secondary a {
    color: green;
}
```

-

```
.primary .secondary a {
    color:green;
}
```

etc

Answer (score -1):

I just come to know !important is not a good solution. So this is the next solution that works.

```
.primary .secondary a {
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: Theres no need to use `!important` here. Could use `.primary > a` or `.primary .secondary a `.

Comment: Shouldn't `!important` be on the green style?

Comment: Terrible answer, there is no reason whatsoever to use `!important` here, it's awful practice and bad advice particularly considering all he has to do is change `.secondary a` to `.primary .secondary a`

Comment: The question already says that he can swap the order. But that will then do the wrong thing with `primary` nested inside `secondary`. I think he's looking for a general solution that gives precedence to the style that matches the closer ancestor.

Comment: Well i didn't know that !important is not a good practice. Thanks guys. I am changing my answer.