# Issue related to Overriding existing CSS class with new Class

Tags: html, asp.net, css, telerik

I have asp.net web application having telerik controls.

I have following textbox in .aspx page:

```
 <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Height="15" Width="115">
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

i have validate

```
d textBox using JQuery as follows:

 $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
                if ($('#txtSearch_text').val() == '') {
                    $('#txtSearch_text').addClass('validation');
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $('#txtSearch_text').removeClass('validation');
                }
            });
```

In Validation class i have set Border-left Property to `1px solid Red`
it works correctly and sets border-left to red when user clicks button when no value is inserted by user in txtSearch TextBox

now problem is that when i hover mouse on RedTextBox. Telerik's inbuild css style sheet executes and i losts Border-left property to none;

How to stop executing inbuild stylesheet of telerik and put my custom css??

Thanks

Comment: is that applying `inline-style` or through a class??

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the stylesheet by using `:hover` pseudo class over the `.validation` class:

```css
.validation,
.validation:hover {
    border-left: 1px solid Red;
}
```

Or for a higher [specificity value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329824/overriding-css-properties-for-a-specific-html-element/21329995#21329995), if it's needed:

```css
#parent .validation,
#parent .validation:hover {  /* Use a selector having higher specificity value */
    border-left: 1px solid Red;
}
```

Finally, you may need to use `!important` keyword to override the inline styles:

```css
.validation,
.validation:hover {
    border-left: 1px solid Red !important;
}
```