# CSS: Make Class take precedence over Element Styling

Tags: jquery, css

I'd prefer not to use `!important`, but I will if there is no other way to make this work.

I have a CSS rule that determines what buttons look like:

```
input[type=button] {
 font: 24px "TF";
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: white;
 background-color: #005299;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then, for certain buttons, when it is clicked, it should toggle a class called `selected`. The class should change the `background-color` of the button, however it does not take precedence over the element styling (the color does not change and Firebug shows the class with a strike-through). How do I make the `selected` class take precedence?

In an extreme case I could also toggle css styling with Jquery, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: `input[type=button]` has a higher specificity value than `.selected`. Have a look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329824/overriding-css-properties-for-a-specific-html-element/21329995#21329995

Comment: @HashemQolami an attribute selector has exactly the same specificity as a class selector, but that doesn't matter here anyway because the problem is with the inline style. (oh wait - yes you're right because it explicitly includes `input` - so `input.selected` would be the same.)

Comment: @Pointy I know that, you've missed the `input` part which gets `0,0,1,1` specificity value. Besides, no inline style would be added to the button. The OP mentioned: `it should toggle a class called selected`

Comment: Yes I see - I'm not 100% clear on what the OP means by "the element styling" but you're probably right that he means that CSS actually posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the only sort of elements in your DOM that are going to have a "type" attribute set to "button" are `<input>` elements, using the tag name isn't really necessary. It's a good practice to stick to the simplest selectors you possibly can; in this case, just plain

```
[type=button] {
  font: 24px "TF";
  /* ... */
}
```

would work just fine. You could then follow that with

```
.selected {
  background-color: green; /* or whatever */
}
```

and the cascade rules would work as you expect.

If you feel that you must have the `input` qualifier, you can double up on the class selector:

```
.selected.selected {
  background-color: green; 
}
```

but that's almost as much of a hack as `!important` (not quite as much, I think).

Comment: I didn't realize that I was double-tagging by having `input` there! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your overriding selector more specific.

For example:

```
input[type=button].selected
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? The specificity of inline styles trumps everything (or so I thought - testing now)

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, but he isn't using inline styles.

Comment: Maybe you're right; I'm not sure what the OP means by, "... the element styling".

Comment: Then I wouldn't be able to attach `selected` to anything besides a button, but for specific example that does work.

Comment: @StrongJoshua: Then you can make a more general more specific selector, such as `html .button` or `input.button`.